# removing observations from assessment split using rsample

Tags: r, tidymodels

Is there a way to replace *only* the assessment split in an `rset` object?

I tried the following:

```r
library(rsample)
library(dplyr)

splits <- vfold_cv(mtcars)

assessment(splits$splits[[1]])
#>               mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4    21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Merc 450SE   16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#> Merc 450SLC  15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#> Lotus Europa 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2

assessment(splits$splits[[1]]) <- assessment(splits$splits[[1]]) %>% slice(1)
#> Error in assessment(splits$splits[[1]]) <- assessment(splits$splits[[1]]) %>% : could not find function "assessment<-"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I know I can extract the assessment and analysis splits and then work with them, but I want to update the `rset` object instead.

Comment: `assessment()` and `analysis()` are functions, which [you can check out if you like](https://github.com/tidymodels/rsample/blob/4fdbd6c05a6ad928831b9a0273b5a2b0f18f9e05/R/rsplit.R#L105); it may help if you share a bit more about your goal here, i.e. why you want to manipulate data in the splits.

Comment: I'm familiar with those functions; they aren't what I'm after. The goal is to build a function that returns an rset object. So I'd like to 1) better understand rset objects and 2) determine if I can alter them directly

Comment: Currently the constructors aren't exposed, but you can [see what other folks are doing](https://github.com/tidymodels/rsample/issues/40), and perhaps chime in with your interest/opinion/use case so we can understand better.